# Trouble with Axis2 https client

Tags: https, client, apache-axis

I have the same problem as in:

[Unable to access axis2 over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230260/unable-to-access-axis2-over-https)

but in my case when I make a request with a client I've written to a third-party https server....

INFO org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (org.apache.axis2.AxisFault) caught when processing request: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Any idea what can I do or what should I configure in my client?¿

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you've never accepted answers to any of your other questions. It's important to accept answers to your questions, in order to reward the people who help you.

Comment: ok, thank you for the advice! I hadn't realised until now.